# Incorrect used memory result by snmp hrSWRunPerfMem

Tags: memory, vmware, snmp

We have few Esxi 5.0 server (with **64GB** memory in each srvr) & snmp is enabled. As per my research there is no oid for used/available  memory OID, it have only **hrMemorySize.0**. 
Therefore in order to calculate used memory, I am trying to get memory used by all processes by using bash script which does the math too.

```
USEDMEM=`snmpwalk -v2c -c PUBLIC -m "/cfg/mibs/HOST-RESOURCES-MIB" $HOST |grep hrSWRunPerfMem. | awk '{print $4}' |  awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }'`
RAW_MEM_BYTES=`echo "scale=3; $USEDMEM*1024" |bc -l`
RAW_MEM_GB=`echo "scale=3; $RAW_MEM_BYTES/1073741824" |bc -l`
echo $USEDMEM Kbits
echo $RAW_MEM_BYTES Bytes
echo $RAW_MEM_GB GB
```

Resulting ...

```
66858364 Kbits
68462964736 Bytes
63.761 GB
```

But on ESXI client I can see only **60 GB** used. Same happening if I try to collect used memory of windows server using above script. It's probably some calculation forumla mistake? I have tried to used * 1000 in calculation but still in-correct results. Its happening with ESXI and Windows Server too If I try to calculate used memory by  hrSWRunPerfMem.
For windows I have many other ways to get used memory as there are standard snmp oids for this purpose. but for this esxi (5) server, I am clueless :(

How can I get accurate results?